# excel formula help =+P17-P18

Tags: excel

what does this formula mean in excel? I am a bit confused. it results value as (P17-P18)/100.

```
=+P17-P18
```

Comment: What is the format setting of the output cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It simply substracts the value of `P18` from `P17`. The leading `+` is useless, just like saying +3 and 3 are the same value.

If you see the result as being `(P17-P18)/100`, I am guessing that P17 and P18 are formatted as percentages, and the result cell is not. Therefore, you see percentages as being 100x their actual numerical values.

E.g.

```
P17 = 50%
P18 = 25%
=+P17-P18 = 0.25 (50% - 25% = 25%, and 25% is actually 0.25, which is (50-25)/100
```

Comment: Agreed on this one good explanation this is what I was thinking as well.